# verify method invocation in AsyncTask

Tags: junit, android-asynctask, mocking, mockito

I'm running Android Junit tests with Mockito. I'm testing an activity that creates an AsyncTask, and I want to verify that a method was called in the `AsyncTask`, but I get an error:

```
Wanted but not invoked
```

The test case looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testFoo(){

// Mocks have been initialized

myActivity.onCreate(null);

verify(myMock).myMethod(params);
}
```

If I run the test like this, I get an error

```
Wanted but not invoked
```

The reason I get the error is because `myMethod` is being invoked in the AsyncTask, but `verify(...)` is being called before `myMethod` is invoked.

To prove that this is correct, I put a pause inside the test like this

```
@Test
public void testFoo(){

// Mocks have been initialized

myActivity.onCreate(null);

thread.sleep(1000); // sleep so the AsyncTask can finish before calling verify

verify(myMock).myMethod(params);
}
```

and the test passed.

Obviously, I don't want the thread to actually sleep. How can I properly make sure that verify is called after my `AsyncTask` completes?

Comment: Could you provide code thats compiles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [verification with timeout](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/verification/VerificationWithTimeout.html).

```
verify(mock, timeout(1000)).myMethod(params);
```

You could also run on a synchronous executor in your test only using `executeOnExecutor`, but then you introduce some test-centric code into your production component, and stray further from testing the actual implementation you want. Timeouts are probably the easiest way to get you as close as you need.